# Django Testing how to use actual database instead of test_db

Tags: django, postgresql, unit-testing, django-rest-framework, django-testing

I am currently trying to do some testing on django application, however info about testing on official documentation is quite small(or probably I didn't search enough). Here is my test (its start actually)

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from rest_framework.test import APIRequestFactory, force_authenticate


class PassengerEditTest(TestCase):
    factory = APIRequestFactory()

    PASSENGER_DATA = {
        "id": 18,
        "given_name": "CHyna",
        "surname": "Jake",
        "birth_date": "1980-11-16",
        "gender": 0,
        "email": "chyna.jake25@gmail.com",
        "phone": "87017777777",
        "DOCO": "ololololo"
    }

    URL = '127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/tickets/profile/passengers/'

    # def setup(self):
    #     user = User.objects.get(username = 'admin')
    #
    #     request = factory.post(self.URL, {'title': 'new idea'}, format='json')

    def test_given_name(self):
        # print "Test given_name start"
        user = User.objects.get(username='chynajake')
        request = self.factory.post(self.URL, self.PASSENGER_DATA, format='json')
        force_authenticate(request, user=self.user)
        # print "Test given_name finish"
```

My problem is when I run on terminal:

```
./manage.py test -s path.to.test.PassengerEditTest
```

it creates a new clean test database, but for this test I need db with actual data from my database. How can I make it so it also inserts all records from actual db not only tables? I am using postgresql

P.S.
I am very newbie at writing test, please suggest some convention, resources and tutorials to learn from.

Comment: You  shouldn't run these tests against your normal database, you'd be better off looking into [using fixtures](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/testing/tools/#fixture-loading).  You could write a script that generates these fixtures files from your database and then use them for your tests.

Comment: So, I can just type ./manage.py dumpdata mydb.json and then load it to my test db? And how can I load data from mydb.json in python code?

Comment: take a lookt to this https://realpython.com/blog/python/test-driven-development-of-a-django-restful-api/

Comment: There is a valid use case for this. We have a large company with a large, legacy MySQL database cluster. I have generated ORM classes for a few of the schemas there, which means about 100 tables. This is not a Django-managed database, we are simply using Django-generated ORM to read the data. All I want is a test which reads a small amount of data from this cluster and returns it as JSON. Standing up a test database doesn't make sense in this use case.